# 301 Redirect in htaccess from NON WWW to https://www with single redirect

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have seen couple of solutions to 301 redirect non www http i.e. http://domain-name to https://www.domain-name but all of them (in my experience) gives 2 redirects.

Either they first redirect from non www to www first and than http to https or in 2nd redirect first and than 1st redirect. One of the example of such code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The best solution would be one 301 redirect which takes care of both i.e. non www as well as http part. Can anyone please suggest me the right code.

Best rgds,

Jai

Comment: The code you've posted would only result in a single redirect, since the first rule redirects to HTTPS (as well as prefixes the www subdomain) and all the second rule does is redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: @MrWhite code by Valeriu Ciuca is perfect bro. best rgds

Comment: Yes. As a side note... since we have found out you are using Cloudflare, the second rule (above) would have actually resulted in a redirect loop. When using Cloudflare (or any front-end proxy) you would likely need to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header - as used in @Valeriu's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this code and I get only one 301 redirect (to https://www.example.com) when I test http://example.com with httpstatus.io

```
# ensure www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

1. The first rule, if your address doesn't start with www will be redirected to the https + www (one redirect)
2. The second rule applies only if your address starts with a www (because of rule 1) and it doesn't contain https. (one redirect)

---

Indeed, your domain http://infocera.com is getting 2 redirects.

Using @MrWhite's suggestion about your domain going through Cloudflare: you should go to your domain in Cloudflare -> Rules -> Page Rules and delete any rule you have about redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to combine both rules into a single one by combining both conditions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That is simple, thus easy to understand for anyone maintaining the site.

The only drawback would be that you have to specify a fixed http host in the target rule. Which is perfectly fine *except* if you host multiple domains and hope to find a solution working for all of them at once.

I would generally advise against such an attempt though. Such general rules have nothing to do with an application logic, one should always prefer to implement such general rule in the actual http server's host configuration instead of using *distributed* configuration files (".htaccess"). That means that you have separate configurations for separate domains, which again allows to place such rule into the separate configuration files while still having only a single actual redirection that is performed.

Comment: Thanx for the code but unfortunately it has 2 redirects when I test in http header status tools. 1st from http to https and 2nd from https non www to https www.

Comment: @Jai That should impossible, actually. Since the target of the rule explicitly redirects to the "www" variant it cannot redirect to a URL without. I suspect you are actually looking at client side cached results. You should be able to see that in your browser's console. Have another try using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: @Jai Or it might also be that you have another rule present somewhere which is applied before above rule comes into play.

Comment: bro plz check for http://infocera.com The code you shared here right now is present and active in the htaccess file.

Comment: So it looks like you have another rule in place then, doesn't it? Could be your provider, in case you are not managing that server yourself.

Comment: Check it here, just a single redirection, as expected: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=452a9e02-36d9-44d7-8866-174f19315f4a

Comment: Bro it shows the final out put and not the no. of redirects it has taken. You may cross check with any tool like https://httpstatus.io/ I have server control. If there is one redirect code (which I have placed in top of htaccess file) to take to final url of https with www than if there is any more redirect code in htaccess, they would not get applied. best rgds, Jai

Comment: You are the boss.

Comment: @arkascha `[NC] [OR]` - should be `[NC,OR]`. This will result in a 500 Internal Server Error - if indeed it is being processed at all.

Comment: @Jai The redirect responses I'm seeing are both coming from Cloudflare. It is Cloudflare that is first redirecting to HTTPS (same host) and then issues a second redirect to canonicalise the hostname. It doesn't look like your `.htaccess` file is being processed.

Comment: @arkascha, I tried your htaccess rule and if I type `https://example.com` it stays there with a 200 response, and no redirect. MrWhite is right about [NC,OR] but not about the 500 internal server error. It's processed.

Comment: @MrWhite yes I am using Cloudflare. What you have to say further plz mention. Best rgds

Comment: @Valeriu Ciuca I tried your code mentioned below and live now also but the result is same i.e. 2 redirects. You can also test at your end. best rgds

Comment: I updated the answer about Cloudflare (credit to @MrWhite for noticing that)

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca thanx a ton your code is working perfect for me now. You may write # ensure www and https in first note. Thanks to MrWhite also and also Arkascha (sorry box doesnt allow me to mention names with @ except one) best rgds

Comment: "MrWhite is right about [NC,OR] but not about the 500 internal server error. " - Ah yes, sorry, no error is reported, but the trailing `[OR]` on the first condition is ignored, so it's AND'd (by default). @ValeriuCiuca

Comment: Sorry for that glitch. Indeed and of course the flags have to be combined. Sorry for that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Better even the `NC` flag should get removed completely. It does not make much sense using it for such purpose anyway.